# How to efficiently implement dplyr do call for lmer function?

Tags: r, dplyr, lme4

I have a dataset with ~400000 rows that I am trying to extract the `lme4` mixed model variance components using a `dplyr` `do` call in R.  The function is:

```
myfunc <- function(dat) {
    if (sum(!is.na(dat$value)) > 840) {  # >70% data present 
           v = data.frame(VarCorr(lmer(value ~ 0 + (1|gid) + (1|trial:rep) + (1|trial:rep:block), data=dat)))
           data.frame(a=round(v[1,4]/(v[1,4]+(v[4,4]/2)),2), b=round(v[1,4],2), c=round(v[4,4],2), n_obs=nrow(dat), na_obs=sum(is.na(dat$value))) 
    } else { 
        data.frame(a=NA, b=NA, c=NA, n_obs= nrow(dat), na_obs=sum(is.na(dat$value)))
    }
}
```

This function is called with a `dplyr` `do` call after grouping the data by four grouping variables. The final `dplyr` call is:

```
system.time(out <- tst %>% group_by(iyear,ilocation,trait_id,date) %>% 
          do(myfunc(.)))
```

Now, when this code is run on a smaller test dataframe of 11000 rows, it takes about 25 seconds. But running it on a full set of 443K rows takes about 8-9 hours to finish, which is awefully slow. It seems obvious that there is a part of the code which is pulling down the performance but I can't seem to figure out whether it is the `lmer` part or `dplyr` that is causing a slow down. I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the way the function is handling the vectorization operation but not sure. I tried initializing the 'out' matrix outside function call, but it didn't improve performance.
Unfortunately, I don't have a smaller reproducible dataset to share. But would like to hear your thoughts on how to make this code more efficient.

Comment: It's the `lmer` part that is slow, it's fitting a complicated model. All `dplyr` is doing is giving it the right data.  You have some little inefficiencies that add a couple milliseconds each iteration (why make `v` a `data.frame`?? just leave it as a matrix), but that will be negligible. Probably certain of the models you are fitting have a weak signal and take a long time to converge. Have a look at `?lmerControl` and maybe you can increase the tolerance and decrease the maximum number of iterations to speed things up.

Comment: Use a print statement in your function to keep track of what iteration you're on, or set `verbose = 1` or `verbose = 2` in `lmer()` to see step-level diagnostics.

Comment: if the structure of your individual data sets is sufficiently similar you *might* be able to do something more elegant, but it would take more work/deeper understanding of the internals of `lme4` (e.g. see `?refit` ... if you have an adequate solution via parallelization, though, I might not bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 
The `mclapply` function from `parallel` package came to the rescue. As @gregor rightly pointed, it was probably `lmer` part which was slowing things down. Finally I ended up parallelizing the function call:

```
myfunc <- function(i) {
     dat = tst[tst$comb==unique(tst$comb)[i],]  #comb is concatenated iyear,ilocation....columns
     if (sum(!is.na(dat$value)) > 840) {  # >70% data present per column
         v = data.frame(VarCorr(lmer(value ~ 0 + rand_factor + nested_random_factor), data=dat)))
         data.frame(trait=unique(tst$comb)[i], a=round(v[1,4])/5, b=round(v[1,4],2), c=round(v[4,4],2), n_obs=nrow(dat), na_obs=sum(is.na(dat$value))) 
     } else {
          data.frame(trait=unique(tst$comb)[i], a=NA, b=NA, c=NA, n_obs= nrow(dat), na_obs=sum(is.na(dat$value))) 
     }
}

#initialize an empty matrix
out <- matrix(NA,length(unique(tst$comb)),6)

## apply function in parallel. output is list
n_cores = detectCores() - 2
system.time(my.h2 <- mclapply(1:length(unique(tst$comb)),FUN = myfunc, mc.cores = n_cores))
```

A twelve core unix machine took ~2 minutes to complete.